# TypeORM not returning data when a where condition is placed on a relation that doesn't match

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

Im trying to find withaccount id condition is placed on relation. Unfortunately, my scripts return null on the main query when related condition doesn't match.

```
 const courses = await Course.find({
        where: {
          diffsess: { id: ds.id },
          deletedAt: IsNull(),
          lessons: {tasks: {takeTask: {account: {id: accountId}}}}  // if this condition not match,      this query return null at all.
        },
        relations: {
          lessons: {
              tasks: {
                takeTask: {
                  account: true,
                },
              },
            }
        },
        skip,
        take: limit,
      });
```

I would to know if any way to get another data in this case.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear. 
I expect that query will return all Courses with takeTask matched accountId condition, if not takeTask = [ ]. But output is give only which Courses matched condition, it removes all another Courses.

Upto now i have to remove condition and use loop function to remove manually which takeTask doesn't meet condition. I dont think its the good way to do

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra for loop.

```
    for (let i of lessons) {
       for (let j of i.tasks) {
         for (let k in j.takeTask) {
           if (j.takeTask[k].account.id != accountId) {
             j.takeTask.splice(k, 1);
             // do whatever you also need
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question?